# Dropdown menu EventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I m trying to get the text value of menu option(dropdown menu). So far i have tried that but no success;

```
var dropD=  $('<div class="btn-group" style="right: 10px; margin: 0 auto; position: absolute"> <button class="btn fontSize btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" style="border:none; background-color:transparent" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Font-Size<span class="caret"></span></button></div>').appendTo(body);
       var ul= $('<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="min-width:10px; margin-left:30px"aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">').appendTo(dropD);
       $('<li class="dropdownFloorplanGroups" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">10</a></li>').appendTo(ul);
       $(' <li class="dropdownFloorplanGroups" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">12</a></li>').appendTo(ul);
       $(' <li class="dropdownFloorplanGroups" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">14</a></li>').appendTo(ul);
       $(' <li class="dropdownFloorplanGroups" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">16</a></li>').appendTo(ul);
```

And a EventListener for the dropdown,

```
$('#dropdownFloorplanGroups').on('click', 'li a', function(e) {
    alert($(this).text());                
});
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attaching the event to the wrong elements. Try

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'li a', function(e) {
    alert($(this).text());                
});
```

The reason it wasnt working before is two-fold

1. You were trying to access classes with a `#`. It should be done with a `.`
2. The class `dropdownFloorplanGroups` itself is **the** `li`. You should delegate from a parent container

```js
var dropD = $('<div class="btn-group" style="right: 10px; margin: 0 auto; position: absolute"> <button class="btn fontSize btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" style="border:none; background-color:transparent" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Font-Size<span class="caret"></span></button></div>').appendTo('body');
var ul = $('<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="min-width:10px; margin-left:30px"aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">').appendTo(dropD);
$('<li class="dropdownFloorplanGroups" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">10</a></li>').appendTo(ul);
$(' <li class="dropdownFloorplanGroups" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">12</a></li>').appendTo(ul);
$(' <li class="dropdownFloorplanGroups" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">14</a></li>').appendTo(ul);
$(' <li class="dropdownFloorplanGroups" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">16</a></li>').appendTo(ul);
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'li a', function(e) {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @tolquito, see the snippet in my updated asnwer. It is working. Perhaps it was not working before because you had appendTo(body) when it should have been appendTo('body')

Comment: i m getting this error on the console
Uncaught Error: [$location:ihshprfx] Invalid url "http://localhost:8383/sincapp_webclient/index.html#", missing hash prefix "#!".
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.2/$location/ihshprfx?p0=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8383%2Fsincapp_webclient%2Findex.html%23&p1=%23!

Comment: @tolquito, sorry I dont know what that error is. It probably has to do with another issue. Again, if you review the code in my snippet its working.

Comment: @tolquito, try posting another question for that error. Hopefully, people with AngularJS experience can help